# How to submit one side data of mui Transfer List with react-hook-form and zod

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, zod

I am using the [mui Transfer List](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-transfer-list/) as a component to select and transfer items from one list to another. The project uses react-hook-form and zod for form data validation and submit.
How to register and submit the left side data?

Here is the code of the moment that the Transfer is called. I can not include the rest of the code.

```
<TransferList leftArray={leftList} rightArray={rightList} />
```

Schema :

```
export const roleSchema = z.object({
  roles: z.array(z.number()),
});
```

The submit function is a function (put) that accepts a number array.

Comment: Additional information: I need to implement a Controller using controler from react-hook-form. However, how to implement this in a transfer list?